# Error "Command failed due to signal: segmentation fault: 11" with Admob interstitial

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios9, xcode7, interstitial

I am looking for help with adding ADMob or iAD interstitials into my SpriteKit game. I have been working on this for a while and still cant seem to get interstitials in my app.

I basically want to be able to call an interstitial between my game scene and game over screen. I have looked around, I used admob and googles setup guide, but when I try to use NSNotification my app provides me with:

> Command failed due to signal: segmentation fault: 11

Here's the line of code I used when this error arised:

```
let notificationSelectorShowAd: Selector = "showAd"

var showAdNotification = NSNotificationCenter
                         .defaultCenter()
                         .addObserver(self,  
                                      selector: notificationSelectorShowAd, 
                                      name: "GameStateOff", 
                                      object: nil)
```

Is there a way to do it without NSNotification or a way to stop this error occurring?